# Ubuntu 14 and Nvidia Prime error

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-prime

I have an Asus S550CM with an Nvidia 635M.
I have just install Ubuntu 14.04 and Prime 6.2 and Switch indicator 0.1 to change between my Intel and my Nvidia chipset and the switch indicator tells me "`sh1: glx info not found`" When I go on the Nvidia X server setting I have nothing about the switch between the 2 chipset.

Have you some idea??

Answer (score 4):

Please install the [mesa-utils](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mesa-utils) package (`sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`) and reload the indicator or reboot your system.